# Split array into columns pyspark-array length variable

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, dynamic-columns

I am having an issue with splitting an array into individual columns in pyspark. The array length is variable (ranges from 0-2064). I tried to do reuse a piece of code which I found, but because the data is huge it does not work.
This is the piece  I tried after converting the array into string (dec_spec_str). It takes forever.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance

```
df2 =df2.select(
        "hashval",
        f.split("dec_spec_str", ",").alias("dec_spec_str"),
        f.posexplode(f.split("dec_spec_str", ",")).alias("pos", "val")
    )\
    .drop("val")\
        .select(
        "hashval",
        f.concat(f.lit("decoded_spec_"),f.col("pos").cast("string")).alias("name"),
        f.expr("dec_spec_str[pos]").alias("val")
    )\
    .groupBy("hashval").pivot("name").agg(f.first("val"))
```

I also thought of an idea of creating data frame of 4000 or so fields and then parsing and writing into that or its copy. If that is better, then please let me know how to do.  I am still getting to terms with pyspark

input like this decode_spec_str = [1.203.3.455,2.334,1.203,0.345]
output like this
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a sample input and expected output? It would be helpful for others to understand your problem better.

Comment: The input is like this. decoded_str [1.203.3.455,2.334,1.203,0.345,...]
output columns will be like below. Imagine ftr1, ftr2, ftr3.. etc are field names and values are from the elements of the array. Eventhough i put it properly, formatting isn ot coming right

ftr1      ftr2          ftr3    ftr4           ftr5


1.203 3.455 2.334 1.203 0.345

Comment: Can you please look into the solution and help accept and upvote if it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, This can be a working solution for you-

## Create the DF here

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,[1.203, 3.455, 2.334, 1.2034, 0.345])],[ "col1","col2"])
#df.show(truncate=False) 
df_grp = df.withColumn("explode_col", F.explode_outer("col2"))
df_grp = df_grp.groupBy("col1").pivot("explode_col").agg(F.avg("explode_col"))
df_grp.show()
```

### Input & Processed Output

```
+----+------------------------------------+
|col1|col2                                |
+----+------------------------------------+
|1   |[1.203, 3.455, 2.334, 1.2034, 0.345]|
+----+------------------------------------+

+----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+
|col1|0.345|1.203|1.2034|2.334|3.455|
+----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+
|   1|0.345|1.203|1.2034|2.334|3.455|
+----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+
```

Now, you will observe the column name is something is not expected, # A little trick to re-order to column names here

```
count = 1
for col in df_grp.columns:
  if col != "col1":
    df_grp = df_grp.withColumnRenamed(col, "ftr"+str(count))
    print(col)
    print(count)
    count = count+1
```

## Final Output

```
+----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+
|col1| ftr1| ftr2|  ftr3| ftr4| ftr5|
+----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+
|   1|0.345|1.203|1.2034|2.334|3.455|
+----+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: This is not working for me. The array size is into 4000 and all. not all values are unique. The number of records in the table will be couple millions. So 4000* 2 million. you cannot have that many columns-right ? or Can you? 
how could i process each record @ a time and then add the columns and possibly concatenate or union
=getting this error
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o16744.pivot.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: The pivot column explode_col has more than 10000 distinct values, this could indicate an error. If this was intended, set spark.sql.pivotMaxValues